# React: how to update a state property of type array of objects

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I have the following state - action history:
[image]

My problem is that I expect a state with zoneCategories : Array[8757] , so I'm doing something wrong in my reducer, which is:

```
let setZoneCategoriesReducer = function (zoneCategories = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_CATEGORIES_FROM_SERVER':
            return [
                ...zoneCategories, action.zoneCategories
            ]
        default:
            return zoneCategories;
    }
}

export default setZoneCategoriesReducer
```

Here is my Store:

```
import {applyMiddleware, compose, createStore} from 'redux'
import rootReducer from './reducers'
import logger from 'redux-logger'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

let finalCreateStore = compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk, logger())
)(createStore)

export default function configureStore(initialState = {zoneCategories: []}) {
    return finalCreateStore(rootReducer, initialState)
}
```

And here my App entrypoint:

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './redux/store'
import { render } from 'react-dom'

let initialState = {
    zoneCategories: []
}

let store = configureStore(initialState)

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Also, my root reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import setZoneCategoriesReducer from './setZoneCategoriesReducer'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    zoneCategories: setZoneCategoriesReducer
})

export default rootReducer
```

I'm mentally blocked right now, any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `setZoneCategoriesReducer` function, you add `action.zoneCategories` as an element of the returned state, which presumably contains the 8757 elements you actually need. Spread it instead of adding directly.

```
let setZoneCategoriesReducer = function (zoneCategories = [], action) {
// ...
        return [
            ...zoneCategories, ...action.zoneCategories
        ]
// ...
}
```

}